# Looking for ready tools to display real-time positions online

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, tracking

we want to show that in a big city like [Palermo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palermo), cycling can be the fastest tool (and at the same time the most ecological). We will give 4 smartphones to 4 users, and there will  be 4 ways to move: by bicycle, by public transport, by foot and by car. We would like to use some smartphone apps to show in real-time in a webpage, in a single map, the route of each user.
I know I can use something like Google Latitude or [Glympse](http://glympse.com/) to track in real-time user position, but I do not know how to put in a single map 4 real-time different routes.

Our goal is to promote the use of bicycle, because we have a high air and noise pollution and the motor vehicle traffic makes mobility very problematic. We will do it voluntarily without any economic budget, then we are looking for some simple mush-up solution that does not force us to produce several hours of development. Something almost ready for "production".

Do you know some solution?

Comment: Do you mean a solution to show each user the real time route of the other users along its own track? How are you going to collect the real time tracks, through a third party api service or are you going to setup your own service?

Comment: Hi giohappy, thank you. I would like to have as output a webpage with a single map. Inside it I would like to see the 4 users movements in realtime. I would like to collect realtime data using a smartphone, because I know it is just possible to do it with apps like Google Latitude or Glympse. But whit these apps it seems impossible to merge real-time routes in a single map; you have a map for each user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution asking the same question in [Quora](http://www.quora.com/GPS/Tools-to-monitor-and-map-in-real-time-users-position), and Ricardo gave me what I wanted: a simple solution that does not force me to spend time in devolpment or in system administration.
The tool is [Greenalp](http://www.greenalp.com/RealTimeTracker/). You can add friends, adjust permissions, log data and view merged information from several users on a single map in real-time. We will use as tracker Android smartphone e the [Greenalp Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greenalp.RealtimeTracker&hl=en).
We have just tested it this afternoon and it works.

Answer (score 4):

> OpenGTS™ ("Open GPS Tracking System") is the first available open source project designed specifically to provide web-based GPS tracking services for a "fleet" of vehicles.

http://opengts.sourceforge.net/

I haven't tried it myself yet, but it sounds like it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Like aborruso I would like to recommend you greenalp. Your Idea is great. Ride on bicycle. And for car or other fleet my suggestion is gofleet. https://www.gofleet.com/product/gps-vehicle-tracking-device
I ride a lot in my bike. Most of the time we ride as a group. Go somewhere else from our busy town. But we don't have GPS system. Sometime we follow only google navigation maps.